# Is there any way to integrate angular as the front-end portion in a django environment?

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, web-deployment-project

I am new to the world of web development. I have a very good foundation on django for backend operations. I am also learning angular for front-end applications. So far, I am quite happy writing in django for the backend, but I don't like to work with the django templates.

My question is, is there any way to integrate angular as the front-end portion in a django environment, keeping the django as the backend?

Also, is there any good UI design courses available, and where (free or paid)?

Comment: You can go with django Rest and angular project

Answer (score 2):

What you were doing was using Django as a backend and frontend framework. But you can use Rest Framework to build an **API**, keeping Django only on the backend. Once you have the API endpoints built, you can consume them with Angular or any other framework.

More info:

[What is an API?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7wmiS2mSXY)

The tutorial in the official website of [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) is a great start.